# Recursively expanding struct definition?

Tags: go, reverse-engineering

How can expand a structure definition to show nested types?  For example, I would like to expand this

```
type Foo struct {
  x int
  y []string
  z Bar
}
type Bar struct {
  a int
  b string
}
```

to something like this:

```
type Foo struct {
  x int
  y []string
  z Bar
    struct {
      a int
      b string
    }
}
```

context: reverse engineering existing code.

Comment: To confirm: at runtime, you would like to generate the Go source code representation of some type, recursively expanding the struct types. Is that correct?

Comment: Not necessarily at runtime, although that would be fine.  I've got some high level containers, and I just want to understand all the things that are getting put into them.

Comment: If you want to display the value, I often use [spew](https://godoc.org/github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew). If you want to walk through the values in the source, I just jump to the definition of each type in my editor as I come to it.

Comment: Wait are you asking how to achieve this as output during runtime or how to modify the syntax of your source such that `Bar` is defined within `Foo` but not independently?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal No, I'm just interested in seeing all of the data in the container data structure in order to understand what the program is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something along these lines to list all fields defined in a struct, recursively listing structs found in the way.

It does not produce exactly the output you asked for but it's pretty close and can probably be adapted to do so.

```golang
package main 

import (
    "reflect"
    "fmt"
)

type Foo struct {
  x int
  y []string
  z Bar
}
type Bar struct {
  a int
  b string
}

func printFields(prefix string, t reflect.Type) {
    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        f := t.Field(i)
        fmt.Printf("%v%v %v\n", prefix, f.Name, f.Type)
        if f.Type.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
            printFields(fmt.Sprintf("  %v", prefix), f.Type)
        }
    }    
}

func printExpandedStruct(s interface{}) {
    printFields("", reflect.ValueOf(s).Type())
}

func main() {
    printExpandedStruct(Foo{})
}
```

I get this output as a result of the above:

```
x int
y []string
z main.Bar
  a int
  b string
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for.  Much appreciated!